# Average of top 2 columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I have a SQL database that has 3 columns like so

```
IA1    IA2    IA3
```

Now I need to find the average of top 2 attributes among the three columns (IA1, IA2 and IA3) and store the value in a third column `FINAL_IA`.

Currently the column `FINAL_IA` has no values. None of the other columns hold null values, all hold `integer` type values.

For example,

```
IA1    IA2    IA3    FINAL_IA
-----------------------------
10     20     30
30     40     10
```

The final table should be,

```
IA1    IA2    IA3    FINAL_IA
-----------------------------
10     20     30     25
30     40     10     35
```

**EDIT 1**

The code needs to run on a Linux machine running SQLPlus.
This is how the table `ia` is created,

```
create table ia (iid integer primary key, ia1 integer, ia2 integer, ia3 integer, finalia integer);
```

sample insert statement

```
insert into ia(iid, ia1, ia2, ia3) values (001, 30, 40, 10);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @Brad I have nothing, I don't know how to achieve this with just SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values are all different, you can use a giant `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when ia1 < ia2 and ia1 < ia3 then (ia2 + ia3) / 2
             when ia2 < ia1 and ia2 < ia3 then (ia1 + ia3) / 2
             when ia3 < ia2 and ia3 < ia1 then (ia1 + ia2) / 2
        end)
from t;
```

In many databases, there are simpler ways to write this, such as:

```
select (ia1 + ia2 + ia3 - least(ia1, ia2, ia3)) / 2
```

**EDIT**
Changed the second case, after trying out the code.

Comment: The computer at my school doesn't have LEAST function yet, but the CASE answer works! At first I thought the second case was an error, but how does that work?

Comment: Hey, I think the second case is supposed to be, 
when ia2 < ia1 and ia2 < ia3 then (ia1 + ia3) / 2.

Answer (score 1):

Would be easier if you provided some basic scripts to create initial state (table, some inserts, etc.) and you provide sql dialect in which are you trying to solve that.

But let's assume that it is a Postgres, so:

```sql
update t set final_ia = greatest(ia1 + ia2, ia2 + ia3, ia1 + ia3) / 2;
```

should do a job. It takes largest from given calculated expressions, and uses that to make an update of final column.

Comment: The SQL needs to run on an old version of MySql which doesn't have the function greatest. The use of CASE solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Good that you have it solved. So, you use mysql or sqlplus which a totally different db afaik? And if this is a mysql - which version is that? I checked, and https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_greatest.asp says that it is from mysql4.0 which is really old.

Comment: I just found out, we use SQLPLUS, and it is some SUPER old version. I don't have access to it right now, but I will update the version as soon I can.